# Application error opening workflow history page

Tags: workflow

This error happens on all types of list item workflows (SharePoint Designer Workflows or SharePoint builtin workflows).

This error happens when I click on workflow status hyperlink:

```
_layouts/15/WrkStat.aspx?List={ListID}&WorkflowInstanceID={WkfInstanceID}
```

This ULS logs are related to this error:

> Application error when access /_layouts/15/WrkStat.aspx, Error=c:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\WrkStat.aspx(114): error CS0103: The name 'allowResumeWF4' does not exist in the current context
>    at System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder.Compile()
>    at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.PerformBuild()
>    at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileWebFile(VirtualPath virtualPath)
>    at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
>    at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
>    at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVirtualPathObjectFactory(VirtualPath virtualPath, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean throwIfNotFound)
>    at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(VirtualPath virtualPath, Type requiredBaseType, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp)
>    at System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.GetHandlerHelper(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath virtualPath, String physicalPath)
>    at System.Web.HttpApplication.MaterializeHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>    at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
>
> System.Web.HttpCompileException: c:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\WrkStat.aspx(114): error CS0103: The name 'allowResumeWF4' does not exist in the current context
>    at System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder.Compile()
>    at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.PerformBuild()
>    at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileWebFile(VirtualPath virtualPath)
>    at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
>    at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
>    at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVirtualPathObjectFactory(VirtualPath virtualPath, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean throwIfNotFound)
>    at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(VirtualPath virtualPath, Type requiredBaseType, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp)
>    at System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.GetHandlerHelper(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath virtualPath, String physicalPath)
>    at System.Web.HttpApplication.MaterializeHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>    at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

I googled but could not find anything.

SharePoint setup:

SharePoint 2013 SERVER running on a VM with a decent 4 cores CPU, 24 GB RAM, Standalone installation, run Product Configuration to create SAs and first Web Application.

SharePoint patch status:
[image]

Answer (score -1):

This is the cure for most any SPDesigner misbehavior. It also worked for me in a situation very similar to the issue in this post.

1. Close SPD2013
2. Delete everything at `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WebsiteCache`
3. Delete everything at `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Web Server Extensions\Cache`
4. Go to SPD2013 options –> General –> Application Options –> Uncheck the “Cache site data across SharePoint Designer sessions”

Also, see this post:
[SharePoint cannot access Workflow details anymore](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/119850/sharepoint-cannot-access-workflow-details-anymore/168018#168018)

Comment: I realize this is a six month old comment, but I felt called to respond given that my searches for a similar error turned this up.  Please read the original question a little more closely.  This has _nothing_ to do with SharePoint Designer.